# iOS device testing via VMWare

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, vmware

I am trying to upload my iPhone app to my iPhone. I'm running Xcode and OS X on a VMWare virtual machine. Even though iTunes recognizes the iPhone when it's plugged in (implying that the USB connection between the virtual machine and the iPhone is working fine), no matter what I do, Xcode does not recognize the device.

The error is:

> **Xcode cannot run using the selected device.**
>   No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

Ideas?

Comment: Does 'xcode organizer (COMMAND + SHIFT + 2) > devices' recognize the device?

Comment: do you have a paid ios apple developer account? ($99/year) Without you can't run your apps on the device. You also have to put the device in developer mode, which you should be able to do in the organizer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'No provisioned devices' implies that you did not add your device to the provisioning portal, or you dont have the proper provisions and certificates installed.

Xcode and iOS are VERY strict about code signing, and so apps will not install on any device (besides the simulator) without the proper certificates and provisioning profiles.  They're very easy to make, and only require an apple developer account available for $100.

From the device side:

Plug In your device, enter the organizer, then select your device and click the plus button in the organizer.  It will ask for login credentials, then if all goes well, will add your device to your developer portal and possibly generate a wildcard provision.

From the computer side:

Enter the apple developer member center.  Click 'iOS provisioning portal' and apply for and download the proper certifications.  Then drag those certifications onto the xcode application icon and it will install them in your keychain and move them to the proper place within the organizer.