# iPhone 6s not connecting to mac osx Sierra on Vmware

Tags: iphone, macos, usb, hackintosh

I am trying to connect my iPhone 6s (10.3.2) to mac osx Sierra (10.13) running on Vmware.

I have changed the USB controller to USB 2.0 and have enabled all three options.

Vmware sees Apple iPhone in devices list, but without any success once I am pressing Connect (Disconnect from Host). Moreover, once I unplug my iPhone from USB cable, it restarts. This behavior happens each time I try to connect it to mac osx (on vmware).

Has anyone come across with this strange behavior, and if so, did you find any solution?

Thanks.

Comment: @UmaAchanta, yes, installed Hackintosh on hardware, not vmware. Apparently Sierra does not recognize apple devices through VM.

Comment: This question is too old to migrate, however, I see value in it and the anawers, so if possible, repost it on the correct site if the question doesn’t already exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works, however you need to edit your `.vmx` file. When connecting your iDevice to the host, write down it's vendor id and product id.

Then open your virtual machine's `.vmx` file, and add the following line:

```
usb.quirks.device0 = "0xvid:0xpid skip-reset, skip-refresh, skip-setconfig"
```

Replace `vid` and `pid` with the digits of the values of your device. Then reboot your VM, focus on the VM and connect your iDevice.

Comment: can not fix problem

Comment: Didn't work on Linux. Device will be connected to VM (means, that in Statusbar of VM you see the Iphone-Icon where you can toggle connection), but even if you activate connection, it is not shown anywhere in macOS (not in Finder, and not in Device-Panel of XCode)

Comment: Weird, yes this answer only applies to Windows. I might will test it on Linux later :)

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio yes, I did. I build an Hackintosh :) I think you have no chance to get it to work on VMWare.

Comment: @suther I found the solution to the problem here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46779998/7295772 thanks !

Comment: @suther you are right. I need to build an Hackintosh. If you are interested in sharing your experience, I posted a bounty of 400 on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139020/macos-on-vmware-doesnt-recognize-ios-device/46779998#46779998 thanks a lot !

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio Developing @ VMWare have really really bad performance. I have an Dell Optiplex 990 with i5 & 6 GB RAM, (for round about 100 €) but it's much faster and more stable to use. But notice, that depending in which Country you live, the EULA of apple deny to run Apple-Software on other than apple's hardware. For my country, that doesn't fit, because our law declare this Rule from apple as invalid. (BTW. In each way, you have to buy SnowLeopard as DVD, to legal use MacOS)

Answer (score 4):

I cannot agree with the selected answer as using Windows 10, VMware 12.5.7 with High Sierra 10.3, iPhone 5s with iOS 11.0.3 and a generic cable it recognizes the device. See the images below.

However, it did not work with Ubuntu 16.04, VMware 12.1.1 (also 12.5), Sierra 10.12.6 (also High Sierra 10.13), and the same iPhone.

I am not sure if it is Ubuntu compatibility issue with VMware/MacOS/iOS. If someone knows, please let us know.

Tip for Windows 10:
1. Scroll to the right and type 'Power Options' in the search field and click on it.
2. Click 'Change plan setting' on your chosen plan.
3. Click 'Change advanced power setting' on your chosen plan.
4. Find 'USB settings' and open.
5. Find 'USB selective suspend setting' and change it to disabled.

In VMware:
- Change USB settigns from 3.0 to 2.0. Also select 'Show all devices'.

[image: VMware window]

[image: MacOs Xcode]

Comment: What you are experiencing might be true because the time I answered this questions was when the new version of macOs was just released and maybe the hackintosh images and/or vmware had not all the issues/support resolved. I am removing the "correct" answer tag from this question.

Answer (score 1):

After long searching and googling for the solution, I came to conclusion that Sierra does not recognize Apple devices connected through USB to virtual machine.

Comment: They do. When I run my vm on a windows machine using workstation pro. The usb connects okay, but on my linux device, it doesn't connect.

Comment: @nnrales I use Arch Linux and the connection doesn't work in 10.13,10.14. I'm now stuck in 10.12. Connection works okay in that old version. Anyone who is familiar with vmware please help!

Comment: wrong. I was able to connect the device with vmware, but currently It stopped working, just after updating from 10.12 to 10.12.6.. I m resetting everything and keeping you up to date
It may also help resetting your usb connections https://askubuntu.com/questions/645/how-do-you-reset-a-usb-device-from-the-command-line