# VMware 14 with macOS 10 don't recognize iPad 10.5

Tags: ipad, macos-high-sierra, ubuntu-18.04, vmware-player

I have

- iPad pro 2017
- Ubuntu 18.04
- Lightning to USB Cable (from box)
- VMware player 14.1.2 (USB 2.0 selected in preferences and installed vmtools)
- macOS 10.13.6

When I first time connect iPad to PC, it ask is to trust to PC - I answered to yes, then in vmware I choose connect to guest OS, again I confirm iPad to trust to connected PC. but still macos don't determine my iPad. after new attepms connecting, rebooting PC, rebooting macos, change USB port, macos still don't determine it and iPad don't ask me to trust PC anymore.

Each time in VMware when I select 'connect (disconnect from host) device Ipad it warn me 'device is used by process .../gvfsd-gphoto2...  will deatach the device from the host OS' and I select 'ok'

So far not my Ubuntu nor macOS show ipad in devices list (in nautilus/finder).

ubuntu:
    $ lsusb
    ...
    Bus 005 Device 008: ID 05ac:12ab Apple, Inc. iPad 4/Mini1

macOS:

```
Mac-Admin:~ admin$ ioreg -p IOUSB
+-o Root  <class IORegistryEntry, id 0x100000100, retain 9>
  +-o AppleUSBEHCI Root Hub Simulation@02000000  <class AppleUSBRootHubDevice, id 0x1000002d1, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), r$
  | +-o iPad@02100000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100000373, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (13476 ms), retain 13>
  +-o AppleUSBUHCI Root Hub Simulation@00000000  <class AppleUSBRootHubDevice, id 0x1000002ed, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), r$
    +-o VMware Virtual USB Mouse@00100000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000002ef, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 13>
    +-o VMware Virtual USB Hub@00200000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000002fb, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 12>
      +-o VMware Virtual USB Keyboard@00210000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100000312, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 11$
```

I have read and try all solutions from here
[macOS on VMware doesn't recognize iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139020/macos-on-vmware-doesnt-recognize-ios-device)
but none helped fo me.

Also when I disconnect ipad from usb - it restarting.

Comment: same problem xxxx

Comment: @kangear It must be connected on how MTP devices are mounted on Ubuntu 18.04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109129/macos-vmware-guest-does-not-recognize-usb-dvice