# Cannot Connect iPhone to MacOS Catalina Guest in Virtualbox on Ubuntu Host

Tags: iphone, macos, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have MacOS Catalina running in VirtualBox on an Ubuntu Host. I've set up USB pass through for the iPhone.

When I plug in the iPhone it keeps trying to connect to the Host and failing. The iPhone vibrates on and off, usually in pulses of 3, and the Trust Computer dialogue on the iPhone briefly appears then disappears continuously. I suspect that it is failing to connect to the Guest and gets stuck in an infinite loop attempting to connect to the Host and Guest in turn.

While it's doing this the Device number for the iPhone in the host, as displayed by lsusb, will be constantly changing.

I've tried USB 1, 2, & 3 with no luck.

Same iPhone can connect to Windows Guest, and other USB devices can connect to Guest Catalina just fine.

I'm using:
Ubuntu 16.04 host
Virtual Box 6.1 with Extension pack
Catalina Guest with Guest additions
iPhone 7

VBox.log:

```
    00:29:22.384244 usb-linux: Reset failed, rc=Not supported. errno=19.
    00:29:22.384304 usb-linux: Reset failed, rc=Not supported. errno=19.
    00:29:22.396584 usb-linux: Reset failed, rc=Not supported. errno=19.
    00:29:22.399738 VUSB: Detached '00007f549c1c4af0[proxy 05ac:12a8]' from port 3 on RootHub#0
    00:29:23.161507 VUSB: Disabled '00007f549c1c4af0[proxy 05ac:12a8]' remote wakeup for configuration 0
    00:29:23.161536 VUSB: Disabled '00007f549c1c4af0[proxy 05ac:12a8]' remote wakeup for configuration 1
    00:29:23.161538 VUSB: Disabled '00007f549c1c4af0[proxy 05ac:12a8]' remote wakeup for configuration 2
    00:29:23.161539 VUSB: Disabled '00007f549c1c4af0[proxy 05ac:12a8]' remote wakeup for configuration 3
    00:29:23.179012 VUSB: Attached '00007f549c1c4af0[proxy 05ac:12a8]' to port 3 on RootHub#0 (HighSpeed)
    00:29:24.821059 VUSB: Detached '00007f549c1c4af0[proxy 05ac:12a8]' from port 3 on RootHub#0
    00:29:25.951225 VUSB: Disabled '00007f549c1c4af0[proxy 05ac:12a8]' remote wakeup for configuration 0
    00:29:25.951237 VUSB: Disabled '00007f549c1c4af0[proxy 05ac:12a8]' remote wakeup for configuration 1
    00:29:25.951239 VUSB: Disabled '00007f549c1c4af0[proxy 05ac:12a8]' remote wakeup for configuration 2
    00:29:25.951241 VUSB: Disabled '00007f549c1c4af0[proxy 05ac:12a8]' remote wakeup for configuration 3
    00:29:25.951242 VUSB: Disabled '00007f549c1c4af0[proxy 05ac:12a8]' remote wakeup for configuration 4
    00:29:25.971921 VUSB: Attached '00007f549c1c4af0[proxy 05ac:12a8]' to port 3 on RootHub#0 (HighSpeed)
    00:29:26.372378 usb-linux: Reset failed, rc=Not supported. errno=19.
    00:29:26.372512 usb-linux: Reset failed, rc=Not supported. errno=19.
    00:29:26.384050 VUSB: Detached '00007f549c1c4af0[proxy 05ac:12a8]' from port 3 on RootHub#0
    00:29:27.160467 VUSB: Disabled '00007f549c1c4af0[proxy 05ac:12a8]' remote wakeup for configuration 0
    00:29:27.160504 VUSB: Disabled '00007f549c1c4af0[proxy 05ac:12a8]' remote wakeup for configuration 1
    00:29:27.160507 VUSB: Disabled '00007f549c1c4af0[proxy 05ac:12a8]' remote wakeup for configuration 2
    00:29:27.160518 VUSB: Disabled '00007f549c1c4af0[proxy 05ac:12a8]' remote wakeup for configuration 3
    00:29:27.188315 VUSB: Attached '00007f549c1c4af0[proxy 05ac:12a8]' to port 3 on RootHub#0 (HighSpeed)
    00:29:28.871512 VUSB: Detached '00007f549c1c4af0[proxy 05ac:12a8]' from port 3 on RootHub#0
```

Comment: I have the same problem with Virtualbox 6.1.16 host Ubuntu 20.04, guest MacOS Big Sur and device iPhone 7.

When trying to connect via usb 2.0, it reconnects in a loop, and after 3.0 it does not connect to the host at all.

Comment: Same here, and it's an iPhone exclusive problem - Android devices are connecting without any issues. So since when Mac OS started to like Android devices?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I have an old ipad & ipad mini that connects.  But the iphone IOS 12.4 displays the same behavior.  I've tried everything I can think of too... still no luck.

Comment: this is for VMWare, but could help in some cases: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139020/macos-on-vmware-doesnt-recognize-ios-device/36224712

Comment: https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/326555-vmware-cant-connect-iphone/?do=findComment&comment=2485726