# My physical iOS device is not detected after running "flutter devices" on macOS running on Virtual Box

Tags: ios, macos, flutter, virtualbox, macos-catalina

I have few confusion regarding testing my flutter app on real ios device on macOS running on virtual box 6.1.

I have installed virtual box on windows and ran my flutter application on simulator. It was working fine. But now I want to test my app on real physical ios device. But for some reason after connecting my ios device with laptop, my physical device connected is not showing up  after entering `flutter devices` on terminal.

Yes, I have done some required setting to detect physical ios device on virtual box.

- I have downloaded and  installed **Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack**.
- I have made sure that "Enable USB Controller" and "Enable USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller" are both selected on my VM machine setting, as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58005032/7290043

Do I need to have same apple ID on macOS and iOS? Is there something that I'm missing???

[image]

`flutter devices` is only showing my simulator, not physical ios device connected

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by simply turning on **USB tethering** on my iOS device.